# How can I import .tab file from mapinfo to QGIS with same color on symbol?

Tags: qgis

I am apprentice Drivetest Analyzer. I want to see color in QGIS like Mapinfo. This is my step.

1.I'm open log file from Drivetest Engineer by Actix

2.I'm export this file to .tab and open in Mapinfo

3.And add vector layer from .tab file to see in QGIS but the color dosen't same like Mapinfo

This is my question : How can I do to see .tab in QGIS with same color in Mapinfo

Answer (score 6):

Nathan Woodrow has developed a piece of Python to do just this, called the "MapInfo to QGIS Style Generator". It works by exporting the style information from MapInfo at a text file and then the python tool reads this into a qml file format for QGIS.

I haven't tested it as I don't have a copy of MapInfo to work on but you can find the instructions and the download on github here: https://github.com/NathanW2/MapInfo-to-QGIS-style-generator/wiki/Using-MapInfo-to-QGIS-style-generator

Comment: That's a better answer than mine, I didn't know this existed

Comment: Just note it's pretty basic and I gave up on it a long time ago.

Comment: I'm a newbie for python and mapbasic. Can anyone explain how to use this method clear more?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to manually change the colour to what you want in the layer properties > style tab. Double click layer or right-click to open up the properties window.

When opening up a layer in QGIS it will assign a random colour to the layer, unless it comes with a .qml style sheet